# Prestashop blocklayered module: the features filters do not work. Why?

Tags: filter, module, prestashop

example: I'm viewing a full category list. I've got blocklayered enabled with price ranges and 'pearl type' feature checkboxes.

The 'pearl type' checkboxes don't work. If I click a checkbox, the vars are something like this:

?id_category=11&controller=category&selected_filters=tipo_perle-akoya

So they're in place, but I do not get any filtered list of products. Worse, sometimes, INSTEAD of a pearl-type-filtered list, I get a price-range-filtered list (but in fact didn't select any price range..)

I'm on 1.5.4.1 official, basic installation.

Any idea?

Comment: did you generate the index of new option from blocklayer module page

Comment: That was the main matter, thank you!
Still, I discovered that the real problem was that I was using the module in 2 places (hooks) at a time. That was causing a variety of issues.